# Convert date to month and day python?

Tags: python

if I have an array of dates:

```
["2012-1-1", "2012-1-3","2012-5-3"]
```

I want to be able to get a result list of:

```
["January 2012", "May 2012"]
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: s/array of dates/list of strings/

Comment: I'd use `datetime` to get datetime objects which you can then work with or write out in whatever format you want ... but I suppose you could split the string on `'-'` and then use a dictionary lookup to map `'1'` to `January` etc.

Comment: use the `map` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[datetime.datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d').strftime("%B %Y") for d in my_list]
```

Comment: Is there some efficient way to remove the duplicate entries in the list?

Comment: @Damascusi: you can use `set` for removing duplicates

Comment: Is there some efficient way to sort such that any item with year 2012 is ordered before any item with year 2013?

Comment: Sorting before converting.

Comment: Then use `"%Y %B"` and sort after.

Comment: Something is wrong because April and August will come before February and March with sorted()

Comment: set(datetime.datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d').strftime("%B %Y") for d in my_list)

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this in three parts if you want to sort by the datetime and cull uniques:

```
dates = [datetime.datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d') for d in my_list]
dates.sort()
string_dates = [d.strftime("%B %Y") for d in dates]
## now we'll cull the list of duplicates
import itertools
[ grouped[0] for grouped in itertools.groupby(string_dates) ]
```